# Insert and delete in a multi level sorted linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

2->7->8->11

|

13->16->17->21

|

22->23->27->29

|

30->32

Sorted Linked List given like above where each node has 2 pointers next and down. For each row starting nodes down points to next row start. Each row has 4 elements, except last one which can have <= 4 elements. Next rows start element is greater than previous rows end element. We need to design and code for it insert of new value at correct place and delete operation. I could not solve this problem.

Comment: Sounds fairly straight-forward. What specifically were you having trouble with, any code attempt that you can show?

Comment: Let say I want to insert 9 then first we have to find the place where 9 is to be inserted (here it's between 8 and 11)  then we have to shift all the elements because each list can have 4 elements except last one. So 11 will now move to second row so 2's down pointer will change.  this shifting code looks tricky to me.  Similarly in case of delete we have to do similar shifting that looks tricky. can you please code it?

Comment: It should not be tricky. The way I see it, you need two functions 1) Push last element to child list, and 2) Pop last element from child list, one of each should be called before insert and delete, respectively, if the length constraint would be violated by the operation. I hope this helps.

Comment: What if  you add 100 values, will the sublists still be limited to 4 elements, or is there a square-root (of the total number of values) playing a role here? That would make sense, as it would allow insertion and deletion in O(sqrt(n)) in many cases.

Comment: Or can the down link be used recursively to limit the vertical length of each list to 4?

Comment: @trincot I think you are right. if we are adding 100 values then size of each horizontal sublist will be sqrt(n) wehre n is total number of values.   Now can you please write pseudo code or algorithm to solve it?

Comment: *I think you are right*: but can you be concrete in your question, and add an example series of inserts and deletes that demonstrates how the list will need to evolve?

Comment: I guess that was  not possible... moving on.

Answer (score 1):

Structure representation and Pseudo code for the add operation is as follows
And we can implement the delete recursively using the add data as example

```
typedef struct sibling{
    int data;
    struct sibling *nxt;
} t_sibling

typedef struct children {
    struct sibling  *sibling;
    struct children *nxt;
} t_children;


add_element(t_children **head, int newdata)
{
    t_children *walk_down = *head;
    t_children *parent  = NULL;
    
    while (walk_down != NULL) {
        if(parent == NULL && Compare newdata < head of current walk_down->sibling) {
            // Code comes here when we add 1 to above mentioned list example
            newdata is added to begining to head of walk_down->sibling
            sibling_list_count++;
            if (sibling_list_count > 4) {
                taildata = delete_end from tail of walk_down->sibling
                add_element(&walk_down, taildata)
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(newdata < head of current walk_down->sibling) {
        
            if (Compare newdata > tail of parent sibling) {
                // Code comes here when we add  12 to above mentioned list
                newdata is added to begining to head of walk_down->sibling
                
                if (sibling_list_count > 4) {
                    taildata = delete_end from tail of walk_down->sibling
                    add_element(&walk_down, taildata)
                }
            }
            else {
                // Code comes here when we add 6 to above mentioned list
                newdata is added to the appropriate location of parent of sibling
                Since above step disturbs the <= 4 property we 
                taildata = delete_end from tail of parent->sibling
                add_element(&walk_down, taildata)
            }
            break;
        }
            
        parent = walk_down;
        walk_down = walk_down->nxt;
    }
}
```